# Log4j2 routing pattern

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I need to configure log4j2 to handle log methods with some pattern which can decide
which log file to use to put log message. Requirements is not allowed define each time
the logger.

All system log messages redirects to app-clutter.log

Now i need the pattern and i guess helper class which can define when redirect log message
to app-errors.log or app-database.log. By default other messages goes to root.log

Programmers should use only some API with several methods

```
void logInfo(String message, Object... args);
void logDebug(String message, Object... args);
void logError(String message, Throwable e);
```

Below is the current log4j2.xml config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">/home/app</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Filters>
    <AggregateDuplicatesFilter level="INFO" repetitionsRate="5" cacheSize="10000"/>
  </Filters>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="file_root" fileName="${log-path}/root.log"
      filePattern="${log-path}/root-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="true" 
immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="file_app-database" fileName="${log-path}/app-database.log"
      filePattern="${log-path}/app-database-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="true" 
immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="file_app-clutter" fileName="${log-path}/app-clutter.log"
      filePattern="${log-path}/app-clutter-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="true" 
immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="file_app-errors" fileName="${log-path}/app-errors.log"
      filePattern="${log-path}/app-errors-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="true" 
immediateFlush="false">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %c{1} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
    </RollingFile>    
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="INFO" additivity="false" 
includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="file_app-clutter"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig" level="INFO" 
additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="file_app-clutter"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
    <AsyncLogger name="APP_ERROR" level="ERROR" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="file_app-errors"/>
    </AsyncLogger>
    <AsyncLogger name="APP_DATABASE" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="file_app-database"/>
    </AsyncLogger>

    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="file_root"/>
    </Root>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear to me.

1. Why are you not using the Log4j 2 API instead of a custom API?
2. Why do you have Loggers named ERROR and Database? With normal routing conventions events from application coded loggers will never use them.

The normal logging API would look like:

```
public int welcome(String myFriend, Permissions permissions) {
    int rc = 0;
    logger.traceEntry("Saying hello to {}", myFriend);
    logger.debug("Registering permissions for {}, myFriend);
    logger.info("Successfully Welcomed {}", myFriend);
    return logger.traceExit(rc);
}
```

The expected way to do this is to add information to your logging events. For example, if you want to log SQL statements then create a Marker named SQL and then add a MarkerFilter so only SQL statements get routed to the appropriate Appender. If you want calls from Hibernate routed to a particular file then configure a Logger for org.hibernate and route all events from that to the appropriate Appender. If you only want Errors sent to a specific file then configure the Appender (or Appender-Ref as appropriate) with a ThresholdFilter that only allows error events.

To use a Marker you first declare one with

```
Marker sqlMarker = MarkerManager.getMarker("SQL");
```

then in the code you would do:

```
logger.info(sqlMarker, "SQL: {}", sqlStatement);
```

finally in the configuration you would include:

```
<Logger name="com.mycorp" level="info">
  <Appender-Ref ref="file_app-database">
    <MarkerFilter marker="SQL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMisMatch="DENY"/>
  </Appender-Ref>
  <Appender-Ref ref="file_app-errors" level="error"/>    
</Logger>
```

This example configuration will route any logs using a logger whose name is prefixed with "com.mycorp", whose level is info, warn, debug or fatal, and which has a marker of SQL to the file_app-database Appender. Log events at level error will be routed to the file_app-errors Appender.

Without a better description of what you are trying to achieve I can't really provide an example configuration.

You can find more information at: [Markers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/markers.html) and [Filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html). You can also find information on how to use Log4j 2 by reading some of these [articles and tutorials](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/articles.html).

Comment: 1. There is a requirement : don't create longer each time developer needs to log something. Instead provide API with limited set of methods. And create some intermediate logic which can decide which file to use to put log message
2. I've change the names if it's a problem

Can you please provide some examples with Markers and Filters ?

Comment: Loggers are normally created as static members of a class and have the name of their class.  So they are only instantiated when the class is first referenced, not every time a developer needs to log something. See if my other updates help.